# How to record user preferences in Android with the support package

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I have a FragmentActivity as my main activity.  I am trying to call up a "user preferences" screen to record some preferences.  It seems that I need to call the PreferenceActivity from an Activity (as opposed to a FragmentActivity).  Is there an alternative to call a PreferenceActivity from a FragmentActivity?

Edit: I am using the compatibility package

Comment: Is PreferenceFragment helpful? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html

Comment: It would be, but I am using the compatibility package and it is not present in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an alternative to call a PreferenceActivity from a FragmentActivity?

No, sorry, `PreferenceActivity` only supports native fragments on Android 3.x and higher. With some care, you can craft preference XML and activities that will support both fragments on supported devices and a classic `PreferenceActivity` on older devices. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Prefs/FragmentsBC) demonstrating this.

Comment: That's funny.  It is actually your book and source code that brought me here!  When I try to use the FragmentsBC code, I get an error saying it can't start the activity (which I assumed was because I am not in an Activity, I am in a FragmentActivity)

Edit: I should add that I am using the compatibility package

Comment: @electrichead: You get an error where saying it can't start what activity? What is the stack trace from LogCat?

Comment: LogCat just has one line:
11-23 14:06:12.532: I/ActivityManager(60): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.wakensoft.everyx/.notifications.EditPreferences } from pid 562

Here is the error stack:
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception ActivityNotFoundException)) 
Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(int, Object) line: 1405 
Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Context, IBinder, IBinder, Activity, Intent, int) line: 1379 
EveryXActivity(Activity).startActivityForResult(Intent, int) line: 2827 
EveryXActivity(FragmentActivity).startActivityForResult(Intent, int) line: 639 ....

Comment: .. cont: The code is exactly as it is in your source (with maybe some new names).  The line causing the error is the "startActivity" call: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, EditPreferences.class));
       }

Comment: @electrichead: `ActivityNotFoundException` means that there is a difference between your activity class names/packages and how they are represented in `<activity>` elements in the manifest.

Comment: Thank you!  I had a brain fart and did not include the fully qualified class name. Your workaround works!

Comment: @electrichead: Thank goodness! Otherwise, I'd have (another) book errata to fix... :-)